# How to fix uneven distribution of hair particles?

Tags: particles

I have these spots on my mesh. I've checked if I was combing them in the wrong direction and also tried adding more particles as well, but I'm still getting these patches in certain areas.

What could the problem be?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is the uneven-ness of the distribution of your vertices across your mesh. Hair particles spawn on your vertices, or faces (you can select which one). Hence, in places with higher vertex counts, there will be more hair particles. My suggestion is to go into *Edit Mode*, select all the "bald" faces and add more geometry. You'll see immediate results.

EDIT: Alternatively, you can select *Random Distribution*. It makes the geometry irrelevant.

Comment: If uneven geometry is the case, then selecting Random distribution over Jittered distribution makes the geometry irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You always get to learn something new everyday.

Comment: The vertices seem pretty well distributed to me; as for changing it to random distribution, I didn't see any differences. Here's how it looks, in case you want to take a look.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehg05mob98l8xpi/Horse_Fur_topo.png?dl=0

Comment: well, that IS evenly distributed. Err, I'm really unsure now. Maybe some settings issue? I've never touched many places of the Hair particle system, just the basics. Maybe you touched a setting you weren't supposed to?

Comment: I did everything I always do, but I'll review the settings. I've never faced this problem before... it's really strange.

Comment: Do you have one of the Children options selected? Funnily enough, I was making velvet and noticed I had uneven patches, especially when the hair was short. Disabling it fixed it, but then had to bump up real hair count.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, a rather silly one to be honest. Basically, some of the hairs were too " flat ", close to the mesh. All I had to do was puff some of them. I’d never thought it could be the cause since there’re other hairs like that and yet I don’t get patches there. Thanks though.